# Typo3 login password hash

Tags: hash, passwords, rsa, typo3

How can I build the rsa hash of the Typo3 login in php manually? I need to create a spider script which just goes to every site, and the problem is therefor I have to be logged in. So I thought I do the loggin via CURL. But then I saw this rsa hash of the password and now I don't know how to convert a password like "blablabla" into such a rsa hash.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find some help out of auto login extension here: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?id=23&L=0&q=auto+login

Or debugging `tx_rsaauth_sv1::authUser`. An RSA-decrypt function is called there. However I don't have the time to really dive into it right now.

---

Another solution is to login once and save the cookies. Then send those cookies with your CURL request.

To make the cookies valid for a longer period, you could temporarily change the backend session time-out setting before logging in. Like so:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['sessionTimeout'] = strtotime('+1 year')-time();
```

You can add/change this line in `typo3conf/localconf.php` (Typo3 < 6) or  `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` (Typo3 6+).